# Why bootstrap navbar component is pushed into the middle?

Tags: html, jquery, css, sass, frameworks

I have copied the navbar code from the Bootstrap 4.6 navbar documentation, and I just added an icon at the beginning of the navbar.
The problem is that whenever I decrease the size of the window and the collapse starts applying the anchor "smile" gets pushed into the middle, I want it to stay in its place after the collapse applies.
What caused this problem and how can I fix it?

[image: Before collapse]

[image: After collapse]

My code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a href="#"><i class="far fa-laugh-beam text-white mt-1"></i></a>
  <a class="navbar-brand ml-2" href="#">Smile</a>

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without css code i can just guess. But i think it looks like `justify-content:space-between;`

Try to gave one of your classes in `<nav>` just `justify-content:flex-start;` or check it inline with `<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark" style="justify-content:flex-start;">`